# Why can't the matlab textscan function read + 22.24 as a float?

Tags: matlab, textscan

I'm currently having a problem with the matlab function textscan.
I got a data file which looks like this:

```
     1,2018/08/14 17:06:15,  0,+ 22.24,+ 22.46,+ 18.18,+0.0000,+0.0005,LLLLLLLLLL,LLLLLLLLLL,LLLL
```

or sometimes when a sensor isn't working properly it looks like this:

```
   1,2018/07/11 17:02:53,  0,+ 23.88,+ 24.78,+ 23.65,+++++++,+ 23.94,+ 23.01,+ 24.33,LLLLLLLLLL,LLLLLLLLLL,LLLL
```

Since the data varies from file to file I am creating a matching formatSpec from the headerline. 
In the 1st case it would look like

```
formatSpec = '%*u %s %*u%f%f%f%f%f%*[^\n]'
```

and in the 2nd case like

```
formatSpec = '%*u %s %*u%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%*[^\n]'
```

I am using the texscan function like this:

```
textscan(fileID, formatSpec_data, data_rows, 'Delimiter', ',', 'TreatAsEmpty', {'+++++++'},'EmptyValue', NaN, 'ReturnOnError', 0 );
```

but it keeps throwing an error on me with the message

```
Error using textscan
Mismatch between file and format character vector.
Trouble reading 'Numeric' field from file (row number 1, field number 4) ==> + 23.88,+ 24.78,+ 23.65,+++++++,+ 23.94,+ 23.01,+ 24.33,LLLLLLLLLL,LLLLLLLLLL,LLLL\n

Error in data_logger (line 31)
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec_data, data_rows, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'HeaderLines' ,startRow, 'TreatAsEmpty', {'+++++++'},'EmptyValue', NaN, 'ReturnOnError', 0 );
```

When I deactivate 'returnOnError' then textscan reads only the first row and except the date/time string everything is just empty. I also tried to use textscan without TreatAsEmpty and / or EmptyValue but I get the same result.
I really don't get why textscan got problems to read e.g. ,+ 22.24 as a float.
When I specify formatSpec to read all the data as strings it works but then I have to use str2num afterwards which I don't really want to do.

I'm thankful for every help and looking forward to understand this behaviour.

Comment: Because floats can't have spaces in them. Either pre-process the file to remove spaces between a +/- and a digit, or figure out a way of including it in the spec.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Matlab doesn't like the space between the + and the number in those fields. I think the simplest solution may be to just tell Matlab to ignore the + by calling it white space. Add the arguments `'WhiteSpace','+'` when you call textscan, like this:

```
textscan(fileID, formatSpec_data, data_rows, 'Delimiter', ',', 'EmptyValue', NaN, 'ReturnOnError', 0 , 'WhiteSpace', '+');
```

Note that I also removed the 'TreatAsEmpty' argument, because once you consider all the + as white space, it is empty anyway.

Another option would be to pre-parse the file and remove the space between the + and the number. You could read the file using fileread, do a replacement using strrep or regexprep, then run textscan on the result.

```
datain = fileread('mydatafile.csv')
datain = strrep(datain,'+ ','+');
textscan(datain, formatSpec_data, data_rows, 'Delimiter', ',', 'TreatAsEmpty', {'+++++++'},'EmptyValue', NaN, 'ReturnOnError', 0 );
```

Finally, if you get stuck where you absolutely have to read as text then convert to numeric values, try [str2doubleq](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28893-fast-string-to-double-conversion), available on the Matlab File Exchange. It is much faster than str2double or str2num.